# ActionBar cut after returning from shooting the camera

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

The problem exists on the phones SonyEricsson. Tested on 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.1.1.

Actionbarsherlock 4.2.0

Tried to do

```
activity.getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
activity.getSupportActionBar().show();
```

does not help! :(

[image]

Comment: Was the camera shot from your application, or from another one?

Comment: In my application. The result we obtain in onActivityResult.